# What can I say about the stability of this system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes

I am investigating the stability of periodic solutions of an autonomous, undamped dynamical system  whose  solutions over the interval of interest $(T,T+\epsilon)$ are of the form $x(t)=A(t-T)RA(T)x_0$ where $R=\mathrm{diag}(1,...,1,-1)$ and $T$ is a period of the motion induced by $x_0$: $x(T)=x_0$. $A$ is a matrix exponential, i.e. $A(t)=e^{tM}$ for some $M$.

To this end, I choose a Poincaré section $H$. Considering a perturbation $\delta x_0$ on the first return state in $H$, if follows that

\begin{align}
x(T)+\delta x &= RA(T+\delta T)(x_0+\delta x_0) \\
& \approx RA(T)x_0 + RA(T)\delta x_0 + RA'(T)x_0\delta T
\end{align}
and since $x(T)=RA(T)x_0$:
\begin{equation}
\delta x = RA(t)\delta x_0 +RA'(T)x_0\delta T.
\end{equation}
But $\delta T$ can be computed from the fact that $x(T)+\delta x\in H$. Eliminating $\delta T$, I found an expression of the form

$$\delta x = B(x_0)\delta x_0.$$

As I understand, the eigenvalues of $B(x_0)$ determine the stability. Below are plotted one component of a periodic solution (in blue) stemming from some $x_0$ and the effect of a perturbation (in orange) after 1000 periods.

[image]

If the blue solution $x$ was asymptotically stable, then the orange curve would "match" the blue one. What appears here is that both curves are "very similar", but shifted. Here are the eigenvalues of $B(x_0)$:

$$\{1.,-0.6+0.8 i,-0.6-0.8 i,-0.98+0.19 i,-0.98-0.19 i,0.25\, +0.97 i,0.25\, -0.97 i,-0.41+0.91 i,-0.41-0.91 i,0.\}$$

and their respective modulus:

$$\{1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.\}$$

The spectral radius is $1$, so the solution is not asymptotically stable. If it was greater than one, it would be unstable. Here are my questions:

- does the spectral radius of $1$ imply *neutral stability*?
- is the phase shift observed in the graph typical of neutral stability?
- am I guaranteed that the perturbated solution will stay "close" from the periodic solution if the perturbation is small enough?
- does this have some implications on the behaviour of the periodic solution if a small permanent perturbation is applied to the system?

Comment: 1. The spectral radius of 1 imply nothing. If I understood you right, this is exactly the same problem as with eigenvalues on imaginary axis when you studying equilibrium stability. If you have non-hyperbolic eigenvalues (on imaginary axis for flows and on unit circle for maps), and all other eigenvalues are stable (i.e., they correspond only to contraction), you have to study the behaviour on central manifold to deduce the stability. 2. What can you say about rhs of your system? was it periodic? or constant? 3. Why is your solution so non-smooth?

Comment: @Evgeny I edited my post to answer your questions: 2. the system is autonomous, so the rhs is zero. Actually I'd like to know if the system would remain close to its autonomous periodic solution if I added a small external periodic force and light damping. 3. The non-smoothness comes from matrix $R$. Physically, it corresponds to a bouncing (like a system bouncing once on the ground). 1. OK, so the fact that my perturbated solution is very similar to the nonperturbated one but just shifted can only be proven by studying the central manifold?